# I am trying to create tab using react but getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have list of components, which is used for respective displays on the page. I am trying to create a tab. I have tab header defined in a component and respective content rendered in a card component.

```
import React from "react"
import FeatureList from "./feature_list"
import Hero from "./hero"
import Tab  from "./tab"
import Card from "./card"

export default function Component({ name, ...rest }) {
  const { items, ...otherProps } = rest
  switch (name) {
    case "feature_list":
  
      return <FeatureList items={items} {...otherProps} />
    case "hero":

      return <Hero items={items} {...otherProps} />
    case "tab":
      return <Tab items={items} {...otherProps} />

    case "card":
      return <Card items={items} {...otherProps} />
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown component name [${name}].`)
  }
}
```

The Tab and TabItem components are illustrated as follow:

```
import React from "react"
import TabItem from "../components/Tabitem"

export default function Tab({ items, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
         return <TabItem key={index} item={item} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The TabItem Component has all which I am trying to embed the Card Component

```
import Link from "gatsby-link"
import React from "react"
import {Tab, Nav, Row, Col }  from 'react-bootstrap'
import Card from '../components/Card'

export default function TabItem({ item }) {
  const { properties } = item
 

  return (
   
      <Tab.Container id="" defaultActiveKey="pre-move-in">
      <Row>
          <Col >
              <Nav variant="none" className="flex-row border-bottom mb-2">
              {properties.map((property, index) => {
                  return  ( <Nav.Item key={index} className="w-50 link text-black bg-gray-300 py-2" >
                      <Nav.Link as={Link} to="#" eventKey={property.name} className="text-dark" active={0}>{property.content} {property.name}</Nav.Link>
                  </Nav.Item>)
                })}
              </Nav>
          </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row >
          <Col>
              <Tab.Content>
                <Card />
              </Tab.Content>
          </Col>
      </Row>
      </Tab.Container>
  
  )
}
```

**Card**

```
import React from "react"
import CardItem from "../components/CardItem"

export default function Card({ items, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <div >
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        return <CardItem key={index} item={item} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**CardItem**

```
import Link from "gatsby-link"
import React from "react"
import { Tab }  from 'react-bootstrap'

export default function CardItem({ item }) {
  const { properties } = item

  return (
    <div>
      {properties.map((property, index) => {
    
        return <Tab.Pane eventKey={property.name}>
              <p >{property.content} {property.name}</p>
              <ul key={index}>
                  {property.cards.map((card, i) => {
                      return <li key={card.page_id}>
                            {card.heading}
                      </li>
                  })}
              </ul>
          
              </Tab.Pane> 
      })}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am receiving this error and I don't how to go about this. I need help to this right. There is another on page error which is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". This error is signified from **src/components/Card.js:6**

Comment: Where are you importing `items` from? It's the most pertinent data structure to your question and I can only see it referenced as a prop (from `...rest` which is very unclear). Remember that `map` is a function only accessible on array data types

Comment: All I want to achieve is to be able to have CardItem passed to the TabItem (The TabItem is the Tab header while the content of it is contained in CardItem). If I don't have <Card /> passed to TabItem Component, it is only displays the CardItem list but clicking on the tab headers, nothing changes.

Comment: if you look at the Components from the topmost code, I passed the props into the individual components i.e. Card and in Card Component, I passed props to CardItem which enables me to display the CardItem contents but HOW I display the CARD component in TabItem (so that when I click on Tab header, the contents display appropriately)

Comment: in your `TabItem` you have an **empty** `Card` in the HTML (`<Card />`).  You need to pass the `items` to the `<Card items="someItems" />`.... it's not really clear where the `items` for the card are coming from, but they definitely aren't being passed on.

Comment: there seems to be some code for a `Component` which does have `items`, but this does not appear to be in use in the `TabItem` code.

Comment: @Claies I have tried to pass it through but it is empty, I don't know how to do thag